# Eclipse is not working correctly with Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I do a basic output stream I have to "run it" twice because the first time it just puts what it had before.

For example if i put `System.out.print("Something");` the output will be **"something"**

But then If I change it to `System.out.print("Something123");` it will ***still*** print out **"something"** as if I never altered the code at all. It's only on the **2nd time that I run the code** that it prints out **"something123"**.

Why does it take **2 times** for it to recognize that I changed my code?

I have looked for similar questions on stack-overflow but the one question that I did find similar to mine the answer seemed vague and unhelpful to the problem.

Comment: try cleaning the project. may be there is some cache issue.

Comment: Also make sure the project is set to auto-build, and that the code is saved prior to invoking the run (and that the dialog to remind you is not turned off).

Comment: @saikumarm that didn't work

Comment: @KevinO it is set to auto-build, it's really strange because that I don't have this problem with my other computer.

Comment: Try deleting build directory manually after each run.. so that next run will compile updated code.

Comment: Maybe you are running it again before the build has finished.  You could keep the "Progress" view open to see.  What happens if you make the change, wait a minute, and then run it? Does it still take two times?

Comment: @WW. I'm not quite sure what was wrong but i installed eclipse neon and it doesn't seem to have that problem anymore,